# setTimeout in Hooks is not changing state

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to upload image and after 20 seconds, if image is not uplaoded I want to close UploadingIndicator component (which appeared with the start of uploading) and display custom WaitAlert component, where user can choose to wait or try to send image again.

But I have problem with displaying custom WaitAlert component. It is not displayed.

Here is my code:

```
import WaitAlert from '../components/alert/waitAlert'
import UploadingIndicator from '../components/uploadingIndicator/uploadingInddicator'
let sendingTimeout

const App = (props) => {
  const [showUploadingIndicator, setShowUploadingIndicator] = React.useState(false)
  const [showWaitAlert, setShowWaitAlert] = React.useState(false);

  saveAsset = () => {

    setShowUploadingIndicator(true)

    sendingTimeout = setTimeout(() => {

      setShowUploadingIndicator(false)
      setShowWaitAlert(true)  //THIS IS NOT DISPLAYING WaitAlert

    }, 20000)

    updateMutation({

      variables: {
        assets: [{
          files
        }]
      }
    }).then(result => {

      setShowUploadingIndicator(false)
      clearTimeout(sendingTimeout)
      setShowWaitAlert(false)

    })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error.toString()", JSON.stringify(error))

      })

  }

  return (

    <View>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={saveAsset} />

      {showUploadingIndicator &&

          <UploadingIndicator />       

      }

      {showWaitAlert &&

        <WaitAlert />

      }

    </View>

  );

}
```

How can I make WaitAlert appeared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The problem was in WaitAlert component.

I added style of main View, where modal was placed to:

```
mainView: {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 10,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sendingTimeout`  is been cleared in `clearTimeout(sendingTimeout)`, then the setTimeout is not triggered after 20 seconds. Try to remove the line `clearTimeout(sendingTimeout)` to see if it works.

Comment: I tried to remove it, but it didn't help. Anyway ".then" part  is in scope only if upload is successful.

Comment: have you tried to remove those thing only to check if the `showWaitAlert` is really chaning?
remove the entire function `updateMutation`, print the `showWaitAlert` in something like {showWaitAlert} only to see if the value is changing. and also update the timeout to 1 second (1000).